# R - How to read csv into integer but not list

Tags: r, readr

```
Food <- read_csv("E:/ProgramData/R/Food/Food3.csv", 
col_types = cols(Subject = col_integer()))   
typeof(Food[,1])
class(Food[,1])
test <- datasets::Theoph
typeof(Theoph[,1])
class(Theoph[,1])
```

```
[1] "list" 
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
[1] "integer"
[1] "ordered" "factor"
```

I read a csv file as a list. The object in it is still a list even though I input the code `col_types = cols(Subject = col_integer())`.

I wonder how to make the specific column to be an integer but not a list, just like the default datasets Theoph.

The class seems different, how could I change the class to be the same as "Theoph" with read.csv function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the type of a column, remember the column is the second dimension of the dataframe, the first being the row. So you must precede it with a comma.

```
typeof(Food[,2])
typeof(Teoph[,1])
```

Another function that you may find helpful if class() which gives more information on the type of the value. typeof() gives only the base type.

```
class(Food[,2])
class(Teoph[,1])
```